# How can I ask `comment-dwim` to leave at least two spaces in python-mode?

Tags: python, emacs

`comment-dwim` (commend-do-what-I-mean, usually <kbd>M-;</kbd>) works well. It:

1. appends spaces at the end of the line until at least some column is reached,
2. if the preceding line also had a comment tailing the code, aligns the comment character, and
3. inserts the comment character for the mode, followed by one space.

In Python one feature is missing to comply with the stringent rules:

4. at least *two* spaces must separate code from the trailing comment.

How can I configure `comment-dwim` to leave at least two spaces in python-mode?

Comment: You can take a look at `comment-indent-function`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26316611/18118915. Or just `let` `comment-column` on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddling with `comment-dwim` may be holding the wrong end of the stick. For me, `M-;` automatically inserts two spaces, the '#' character, and a space, following which point is placed. If it's not doing that for you, then you may have reconfigured it somewhere else, possibly accidentally.

I suggest an alternative is to have a 'format-on-save' option enabled, which will do this for you without fussing in your `.emacs` or with customize.

```
(use-package python-black :after python
    :hook (python-mode . python-black-on-save-mode)
    :bind ("C-c p C-f" . 'python-black-buffer))
```

I use `black`, but any alternative formatter should do the same. I never worry about how my file is formatted, because `black` fixes it for me automatically.

From the docs for `black`:

```
Black does not format comment contents, but it enforces two spaces   
between code and a comment on the same line, and a space before the 
comment text begins.
```

Comment: Good to know. But since I also like to use flycheck while coding, I'd much rather if it's correct all along so I don't have to see squiglies all over, rather than just correct when saving.